# Connect to openshift ftp using sublime text 3

Tags: openshift, sublimetext3, sftp

Connect to openshift ftp using sublime text 3. I already tried using SFTP plugin. This is my config file:

```
{
// The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
// Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

// sftp, ftp or ftps
"type": "sftp",

"sync_down_on_open": true,
"sync_same_age": true,

"host": "nodebb-htforum.rhcloud.com",
"user": "56d3d2e189f5cfad110001a1",
"password": "******",
"port": "22",

"remote_path": "/",
//"file_permissions": "664",
//"dir_permissions": "775",

//"extra_list_connections": 0,

"connect_timeout": 30,
//"keepalive": 120,
"ftp_passive_mode": true,
//"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
"ssh_key_file": "C:/Users/Nihal/.ssh/id_rsa",
//"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

//"preserve_modification_times": false,
//"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
//"remote_locale": "C",
//"allow_config_upload": false,
}
```

Comment: you forgot to mention what problem you're facing

Comment: @ericosg I can't connect to the openshift server.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the problem is? "can't connect" is not very descriptive. What do you actually see? Do you get any errors? Please take a moment to read through [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You can always [edit] your question.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Its not connecting, If i set the type to SFTP(which is the right option) It will give "Connection timeout" error. If i set ftp or ftps, It will go on connecting. But ends up "connection disconnected" error.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct hostname? Are you sure you're using "FTP over SSH", and *not* "FTP over SSL"? You have port 22 in your config, so I assume you want the former? But maybe you need the latter? Make sure you can connect to port 22 on that server. Perhaps it's blocked by a firewall?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker No. I posted this question. Because i can connect with filezilla using the same settings of hostname, sftp, username, and password.

Comment: If you have access to the server you can try checking the logs.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker But i think its not a error from server. It should be settings error from sublime text. Anyway, I'll try to check the logs now.

Comment: The logs may still show something useful. And if they show *nothing* then that's also useful, since then you can probably exclude 50% of the problem area: the server ;-)

Comment: try a blank password to use the ssh keys

Comment: @ericosg Ok. Let me try it quick

Comment: @ericosg Same error "Sublime SFTP Connection Timeout". Tried increasing the timeout too. May it be because of the ssh key file(pls check my code above)?

Comment: maybe try without the file and without a password etc

Comment: @ericosg Still same error message "Connection timeout". Should be something wrong with sublime or SFTP plugin

Answer (score 1):

To use sftp of Sublime Text connect to OpenShift you can follow the steps below:

```
1. Install Client tools (on windows):
    https://developers.openshift.com/getting-started/windows.html#client-tools

    * If you using MacOS: Only install rhc:
        $ sudo gem install rhc 

        If you get the "Operation not permitted" (EPERM) error, run instead:
        $ sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin rhc

        If you encounter any dependency issues, you may need to run:
        $ sudo gem update

2. Create RSA Key:

    rhc setup

    You’ll be prompted for your OpenShift username and password:
        Login to openshift.redhat.com: Your email (user@example.com)
        Password: Your password

 follow the steps setup to create private key and public key. this step too upload public key to Your OpenShift App.

3. Config sftp connect to OpenShift App:
All Os can use:

    type: sftp
    Host: [your app name]-[your openshift domain].rhcloud.com
    User: App ID (https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application/687ac8fd0c1e665b5300011b-[your app name] => app id is: 687ac8fd0c1e665b5300011b)

    remote_path: /var/lib/openshift/your app id/app-root/repo/php/ (for php  app or wordpress app: /var/lib/openshift/your app id/app-root/data/current)

3.1 For Linux and MacOS use sftp need rsa key:
    Pass: password login to OpenShift)
    Port: 22
    ssh_key_file: "~/.ssh/id_rsa"

3.2 For Windows Sublime Text use psftp need private key:
    //Pass: (not use)
    //Port: 22 (not use)
    ssh_key_file: "C:\\Users\\Your username\\.ssh\\your private key.ppk" (More Step 4)
```

4. How to create Private Key from Public Key use [Puttygen](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/puttygen.exe)

   ```
   Download and Open Puttygen then click on Generate button and move mouse to complete public key.

   Kick on Save private key button and Save to C:\Users\Your username\.ssh\your name private key.ppk

   On Openshift at Settings tab kick Add a new key and paste public key just create at Puttygen to key content on Opnshift.
   ```

This tutorial working on Linux, MacOS and Windows for Sublime Text 2, 3.

Final: Right mouse on your project folder => SFTP/FTP => Browse Remote.

Done!